# Copy column content from one table to another mysql

Tags: mysql, osclass

I am trying to populate column `s_phone_mobile` from `oc_t_user` table to `oc_t_item` table in mysql database. I use the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `oc_t_item` (s_phone_mobile) 
SELECT s_phone_mobile
FROM   oc_t_user;
```

But I get the following error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`poljo_test`.`oc_t_item`, CONSTRAINT `oc_t_item_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_i_category_id`) REFERENCES `oc_t_category` (`pk_i_id`))
```

I realize this may be duplicate question, but every "trick" I tried did not work for me.

Comment: Please show the table definitions for `oc_t_item` _and_ any tables with which it has a relationship through primary/foreign key.

Comment: Hi, thanx for the reply. You mean table structures?

Comment: yes please show me the structures.  My guess is that the problem will be easy to spot with this information.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen   Is there any way I can insert screenshots here? I do not know how else to show what you need. Should we continue in chat maybe?

Comment: sure you can open a chat, better than endless comments.

Comment: Ok, better you open chat please, because I do not know how :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129982/discussion-between-tim-biegeleisen-and-nancy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is being caused by your insert specifying only a value for `s_phone_mobile`, effectively specifying `NULL` for the three foreign keys which this table contains.

A foreign key constraint in MySQL will ensure that your insert refers to foreign keys which either exist, or possibly allowing `NULL` if you defined the keys to be nullable.  My guess is that at least one of the following keys is not nullable:

```
fk_i_user_id
fk_i_category_id
fk_c_currency_code
```

So, to fix this problem, you should also insert foreign key values for the above three keys, unless a key allow `NULL` and you are OK with that.  And make sure that the values specified actually correspond to records in the respective parent tables.